# Better option to save huge data internally android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an issue of saving app data internally on device, Well this go like below:
App is service based. We send a request a for particular home project and it will respond with an image of the project and a list of operations. And they want every link to be clickable and on click of that show more links with some text and images. Means lot of data to be handle.

The data which store internally should also get updates. So what could be the better option of saving it. Download files, download more files when update is required or go with SQLite database, which will update the existing db only.

Till now I am finding to create sqlite db as a better option, but still I want to know which could be the better option. I know this would create a memory issue, but this is what client want.

Comment: I am actually not getting your point. If you only want to show data from remote server, why do you want to download it?

Comment: So you want to store a lot of images?

Comment: Yes, there are number of images and rest data too. And app is already showing data from remote server, but this is now client requirement, he want to save data internally, because he don't want to wait, every time data loads from server. He wants one's load won't load it again.

Comment: Also saved data should be update time to time.... I know, this is not logical but this is the situation and what could be the solution.

Comment: You have to create cache like storage, In which if image is already exists, it will load from cache(which is a folder in your mobile).If not, then it will load from url.

Comment: Try https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache it can be used to provide a cache on Disk. This is what you may looking for!